# Cannot use instanceof when dynamically importing files

Tags: typescript

I have an error, when importing files with a custom loader. When checking to see if an imported property is an instance of the class to import, I get the error `The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`

This is my code:

```js
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
export abstract class Item {
    // ... Different Item properties E.G Name
}

// Type for a collection of items or array
export type ItemCollection<Instance extends Item> =
    | Map<string, Instance>
    | Instance[];

export class Loader {
    private loadItem<Instance extends Item>(
        collection: ItemCollection<Instance>,
        item: Instance
    ) {
        if (collection instanceof Collection) {
            collection.set(item.name, item);
        } else {
            collection.push(item);
        }
    }

    public async loadItems<Instance extends Item>(
        collection: ItemCollection<Instance>,
        item: Instance,
        dirs: string[]
    ) {
         for (const dir of dirs) {
            const files = /* Function to get paths for each directory */
            for (const file of files) {
                const importFolder = await import(file);

                for (const exportedItem in requireFolder) {
                    const importedInstance = requireFolder[exportedItem];

                    if (!(importedInstance instanceof item)) continue; // < The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.
                  
                    this.loadItem(collection, importedInstance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for the error?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `ItemCollection` and `Collection<,>` types?

Comment: I think you want `importedInstance instanceof Item`, not `importedInstance instanceof item`. Type-names are `PascalCased`, not `camelCased` - but note `instanceof` only works for `class` types, not `type` or `interface` types.

Comment: Sorry, the Collection is justan extension of a map in a library I use

Comment: "I think you want importedInstance instanceof Item, not importedInstance instanceof item. Type-names are PascalCased, not camelCased - but note instanceof only works for class types, not type or interface"   

This isn't the desired behaviour, the function gets a collection and instance, and will load all of the instances to the given instance to the collection. Because of this I need to check the `exportedItem` is an insatnce of the given `item`

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the `instanceof` operator works and what it does: the right-hand operand of `instanceof` must be a reference to a constructor function.

Comment: What dia said: you need to get the constructor of your target 'item'; for a normal object, you can find: let itmCls = item.prototype.constructor;  if (impInst instance of itmCls) ... or some such